# Function getting called asynchronously in OCaml

Tags: ocaml

I am modifying the facebook/pfff tool, specifically [this file](https://github.com/facebook/pfff/blob/master/lang_java/analyze/graph_code_java.ml).

I am appending details (nodes and edge), in graph_code_java.ml, as and when as nodes and vertices are encountered to two separate files: Edges.json and GraphSON.json.

In the end, after execution of everything I call function cleanup_graphson, which merges Edges.json and GraphSON.json.

Here is what graph_code_java looks like after I modified it:

```
let build ?(verbose=true) ?(only_defs=false) root files =
  let g = G.create () in
  G.create_initial_hierarchy g;

  let lookup_fails = Common2.hash_with_default (fun () -> 0) in

(* step1: creating the nodes and 'Has' edges, the defs *)
...
(* step3: creating the 'Use' edges that can rely on recursive inheritance   *)
if verbose then pr2 "\nstep3: extract uses";
files +> Console.progress ~show:verbose (fun k ->
List.iter (fun file ->
 k();
 let readable = Common.readable ~root file in
 let ast = parse ~show_parse_error:false file in
 extract_defs_uses ~phase:Uses ~g ~ast ~readable ~lookup_fails;
));
end;
(* step 4: Merge Edges.json and GraphSON.json *)
if !write_to_graphson = true then
  begin
    pr "cleaning up";
    GS.cleanup_graphson;
  end;
g
```

The function cleanup_graphson looks like:

```
let cleanup_graphson =
  pr "Cleaning up!";
  Common.append_file "GraphSON.json" "] \n";
  Common.append_file "Edges.json" "] \n";
  let str = Common.read_file "Edges.json" in
  Common.append_file "GraphSON.json" str
```

But when I run the program, cleanup_graphson is called *before* everything else (step 1, step 2, step 3). All the other steps are running in sequence except this. I am not sure why this is the case, is it because file operations are being performed? Has anyone else faced this issue?

P.S: The code for the Console.progress is [here](https://github.com/facebook/pfff/blob/master/commons/console.ml).

Thanks for looking at my question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you're specifically using multi-threading, there's basically no chance any code being executed asynchronously.

Without knowing anything about this code, I'd suspect a buffering problem. Maybe the computation is happening in the order you expect, but the output of `pr` is coming out before other output. This can happen pretty easily when a program uses two radically different ways of writing output.

Comment: Thanks for responding, turned out that I defined cleanup_graphson as a variable and not a function.

Answer (score 3):

cleanup_graphson was a variable, and not a function. When I modified it to below, it executed sequentially. I added a () as a argument to cleanup_graphson.

```
let cleanup_graphson ()=
  pr "Cleaning up!";
  Common.append_file "GraphSON.json" "] \n";
  Common.append_file "Edges.json" "] \n";
  let str = Common.read_file "Edges.json" in
  Common.append_file "GraphSON.json" str
```